# Perl - Convert IPv4 address to hexadecimal

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl script that asks user to input their ipv4 address and convert it into hexadecimals.
For example, user enters "130.130.68.1" which will return "0x82.0x82.0x44.0x01". How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x82.0x82.0x44.0x01`:

```
my $hex =
   join ".",
      map { sprintf "0x%02X", $_ }
         split /\./,
            $ip;
```

or

```
my $hex = $ip =~ s/[^.]+/ sprintf "0x%02X", $& /reg;
```

---

That said, `0x82.0x82.0x44.0x01` is a really weird way of writing 82822601<sub>16</sub>, the 32-bit number `130.130.68.1` represents.

`0x82824401`:

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );

my $hex = '0x' . unpack('H*', inet_aton('130.130.68.1'));
```

`0x82.82.44.01`:

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton );

my $hex = '0x' . join('.', unpack('(H2)*', inet_aton('130.130.68.1')));
```

Both of these also with domain names.

Comment: The ip address is a typo. its 130.130.68.1

Comment: I most commonly write this as 0x82_82_44_01. It's not different and the `_` are meaningless; they are there for the humans.